# OnItemLongClick in Infinite Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I am creating an Image gallery for my Android app and I need it to loop through images infinitely. To achieve this I am using the Infinite Gallery widget found [here](http://blog.jmsliu.com/138/android-infinite-loop-gallery.html) (Code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/infinite-gallery/source/browse/#svn/trunk/infiniteGallery/src/com/jms)). The gallery works very well, however I am having trouble implementing a long press function. I am not trying to create a context menu, just trying to call another method.

Adding an onItemClickListener to the InfiniteGallery object in InfiniteGalleryActivity has not worked.

Comment: I would ask the developer, as he probably knows a lot more about the Infinite Gallery than any of us here at SO. What happens when you use `onItemLongClickListener`?

Comment: I posted a comment on his blog, but figured I'd try here as well. When using onItemLongClickListener nothing at all seems to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, implementing the onLongPress(MotionEvent e)??

Information right here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html

Hope this helps you out =)